# Coadjoint representation $Ad^*$ of the Heisenberg group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, harmonic-analysis

The Heisenberg group $H^3$ is the set $\mathbb C\times \mathbb R$ endowed with the group law
$$ (z,t)\cdot(w,s) =\left (z+w, \,t+s+\tfrac{1}{2}\Im m(z \bar{w})\right). $$
For $z=x+ i  y \in \mathbb C$ and $t\in \mathbb R$.
I would like to know, what is the expression of the coadjoint representation $Ad^*$ of $H^3$ ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coadjoint action $Ad^*$ is the contragredient of $Ad$ and given on $H_3^*$ by $Ad^* (g)=(Ad \, g^{-1})^*$. This can be computed explicitly, e.g., see section $8.4$ on page $203$ [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~margalit/repthy/Representation%20of%20Linear%20Groups%20copy.pdf). The start is to compute
$$
(Ad \, g)Y=gYg^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & c \cr 0 & 1 & b \cr 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & x & z \cr 0 & 0 & y \cr 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & c \cr 0 & 1 & b \cr 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$
explicitly.

Comment: @  D. Burde, thank you very much for your help

Comment: hello D. Burde, just, I do not understandon, in the page:213, how he found that $Ad^* \eta = \tilde{x}_* X_* +  \tilde{y}_* Y_*  + \tilde{z}_* Z_* $; where $ \tilde{x}_*,  \tilde{y}_*$ and $ \tilde{z}_*$ are given in (8.12).

Comment: This is because of the line before where $Ad g^{-1})$ is computed. Look at the matrix there to see the transformations of $(8.12)$.